# How to use threadpoolexecutor in infinite loop in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, threadpoolexecutor

I am trying to make my program faster, using `ThreadPoolExecutor`. But this is not working it keeps closing without giving any error. I am using `ThreadPoolExecutor` in the while loop this might be a reason for the error.

Here is the code snippet:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor as executor
import class1,class2,class3

pool = executor(5)
obj1= class1()
obj2= class2(arg)
obj3= class3(arg)
cap =cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read() 
    image = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.flip(frame,1),cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    if ret: 
        pool.submit(obj1.funct1,image)
        pool.submit(obj2.funct2,image =image,arg=arg)
        pool.submit(obj3.funct3,image =image,arg=arg)
                
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
        close_window(cap)
        pool.shutdown()
        break
```

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your code is *too* minimal and therefore not reproducible. As an aside: your check `if ret:` should precede your call to `cv2.cvtColor`. Also, are you submitting new tasks to the pool without awaiting there completion in each loop iteration faster than they can be processed? If so and if there are a large number of frames, you will exhaust memory.

Comment: All functions do not depend on each other and I want to run each function separately and continuously without waiting to complete other functions, because all these functions are image processors all should be terminated by pressing the ESC button.